# Remove spaces from empty lines in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

Earlier, in windows, when it used to press enter twice in vscode in order to enter two blank lines, the first line entered used to have its tab spaces deleted automatically. But now, when I switched to ubuntu 20.04, it is no longer doing that. How do I bring the feature back, it helped in decreasing file size

Comment: key combo `Ctrl+K Ctrl+X`

Comment: @rioV8 Thankyou very much, it is working now. Please post the comment as an answer so that I could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSC has a command **Trim Trailing Whitespace**, the standard key binding is `Ctrl+K Ctrl+X`

It removes the trailing whitespace from the current selection. If nothing selected it uses the whole file.